# Toggle on/off markers in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, toggle, marker

I'm new to JavaScript and have just pieced the following code together amateurly. There may be many things wrong with it, but it seems to be working for me at the moment.

I'm trying to create toggle buttons for my markers, so there is one button to show/hide the "drinks" markers, one button to show/hide the "bands" markers and so on.

```
var drinks = [
    ["Drinks Station #3", 51.49811, -0.06743],
    ["Drinks Station #4", 51.49652, -0.04596],
    ["Drinks Station #1", 51.50626, -0.01049],
    ["Drinks Station #2", 51.50726, -0.05505]
];

var bands = [
    ["<b>West End Musical Choir</b>", 51.50962, -0.05531],
    ["<b>Gugge 2000</b>", 51.51056, -0.04172],
    ["<b>Cyclehoop Music Bike</b>", 51.50848, -0.02247],
    ["<b>Manorfield Primary Steel Band</b>", 51.50682, -0.01061],
    ["<b>Batala London</b>", 51.50441, -0.01718],
    ["<b>The Dhol Company</b>", 51.50547, -0.0419],
    ["<b>South London Jazz Orchestra</b>", 51.49909, -0.05595],
    ["<b>Pantasy Steel Band</b>", 51.49855, -0.06921],
    ["<b>The Blend Choir</b>", 51.49617, -0.04101],
    ["<b>DJ Truck</b>", 51.49536, -0.04538],
    ["<b>Nostalgia Steel Band</b>", 51.48771, -0.03764],
    ["<b>Popchoir</b>", 51.48135, -0.02522],
    ["<b>Hosenbrass (Roaming)</b>", 51.48192, -0.00957]
];

var relay = [
    ["<b>Relay Exchange #1</b>", 51.50309, -0.01992],
    ["<b>Relay Exchange #2</b>", 51.50886, -0.03309],
    ["<b>Relay Exchange #3</b>", 51.49904, -0.05727]
];

var start = [
    ["<b>The Vitality Big Half Start</b>", 51.50921, -0.0673663]
];

var finish = [
    ["<b>The Vitality Big Half & The Little Half Finish</b>", 51.48291, -0.00989]
];

function initGoogleMap() {

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.49789, -0.03441),
        styles: [{
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#ebe7f0'
            }]
        }, {
            elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
            stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }]
        }, {
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#DADADA'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'administrative.locality',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'administrative.neighborhood',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'administrative.neighborhood',
            elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
            stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'poi',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }],
        }, {
            featureType: 'poi',
            elementType: 'labels.icon',
            stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }],
        }, {
            featureType: 'poi.park',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'poi.park',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#c2b5d1'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#d6cde0'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#d6cde0'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#c2b5d1'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'road.highway',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#d6cde0'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'road.highway',
            elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#d6cde0'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'road.highway',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#c2b5d1'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'transit',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#d6cde0'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'transit.station',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#000000'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'transit.station.rail',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#000000'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'water',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#d6cde0'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'water',
            elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#c2b5d1'
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: 'water',
            elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
            stylers: [{
                color: '#c2b5d1'
            }]
        }]
    });

    var icon = {
        url: "icon_link", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
    };

    var iconTwo = {
        url: "icon_link", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15) // anchor
    };

    var iconThree = {
        url: "icon_link", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
    };

    var iconStart = {
        url: "icon_link", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(36, 60), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(18, 60) // anchor
    };

    var iconFinish = {
        url: "icon_link", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(36, 60), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(18, 60) // anchor
    };

    function placeMarker(loc) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            zIndex: 1
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
            infowindow.setContent("<div id='infowindow'>" + loc[0] + "</div>");
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function placeMarkerTwo(loc) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: iconTwo,
            zIndex: 1,
            type: bands
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
            infowindow.setContent("<div id='infowindow'>" + loc[0] + "</div>");
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function placeMarkerThree(loc) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: iconThree,
            zIndex: 1
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
            infowindow.setContent("<div id='infowindow'>" + loc[0] + "</div>");
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function placeMarkerStart(loc) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: iconStart,
            zIndex: 1
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
            infowindow.setContent("<div id='infowindow'>" + loc[0] + "</div>");
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function placeMarkerFinish(loc) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: iconFinish,
            zIndex: 1,
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
            infowindow.setContent("<div id='infowindow'>" + loc[0] + "</div>");
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++) {
        placeMarker(drinks[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < bands.length; i++) {
        placeMarkerTwo(bands[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < relay.length; i++) {
        placeMarkerThree(relay[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
        placeMarkerStart(start[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < finish.length; i++) {
        placeMarkerFinish(finish[i]);
    }

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
        'route_Link', {
            suppressInfoWindows: false,
            map: map,
            preserveViewport: true
        });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
        'Park_Link', {
            suppressInfoWindows: false,
            map: map,
            preserveViewport: true
        });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initGoogleMap);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you tried that didn't work (including the HTML required to trigger the filtering).

Comment: Related question: [toggle google maps markers by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968853/toggle-google-maps-markers-by-category)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `visible` property of any Marker object. For example, call toggleBars() A Button is pressed:

```
   function toggleBars(){
    bars.forEach(bar => {
        bar.setVisible(!bar.getVisible())
    })
   }
```